# Crystal Report continuous if statement?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have 12 check boxes in my database and want crystal report to look at each one.

- If the first one is true I want it to `return a word`,
- if it's false `return nothing`.

Ideally, I want it to show all the ones that are true listed side by side.

Example: if 1, 3, and 5 are true show the name of the field as Dodge, Chevy, Nissan.

My statement I have is

```
//01
(
If {Make.logical_1} = true 'Dodge' else''
);
//02
If {Make.logical_2} = true 'Chevy' else''
);
//03
(
If {Make.logical_3} = true 'Nissan' else''
);
```

There are no errors but it only returns the last if statement, not 1st and 3rd if 1st is true as well.  I can also leave out the else'' with same wrong results

It should show as Dodge Nissan
Please help!!

Comment: What syntax is this? Looks wrong.... doesn't crystal report throw any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use this:

```
TRIM((If {Make.logical_1} = true 'Dodge ' else '') 
   & (If {Make.logical_2} = true 'Chevy ' else '')
   & (If {Make.logical_3} = true 'Nissan ' else ''));
```

Comment: Do you know how to add a bullet before each one that gets listed?

Comment: @LisaCostello if that worked why dont you accept it as the answer.

Comment: I found how to add a bullet!